# How do you save a python flickrapi response object as an XML file

Tags: python, api, flickr

```
import sys

import os

import urllib

from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

import flickrapi

api_key = 'myApiKey'

api_password = 'Mysecret'

flickrClient = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, api_password)

photos = flickrClient.photos_getinfo(photo_id='2124494179')

//tree=ElementTree(flickrClient.photos_getinfo)

print (photos)
```

I was trying to write the Flickr response into file to save the information using `ElementTree`,
but my attempts were unsuccessful. How can I save the obj value as `xml/txt` file.

I'm using `flickr.photos.getInfo` method to collect data about images. Sorry but I need details to overcome the error `<Element rsp at 101463b00>`. BTW I'm starting with one image to see how the code will work.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is helpful

```
import json
with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
  json.dump(data, outfile)
```

and this could be interesting too

**[Python Flickr API](https://github.com/alexis-mignon/python-flickr-api) by Alexis Mignon**

Comment: actually I tried the code but I had an error "typeError: <Element rsp at 101574f80> is not JSON serializable". I have this obj "data = flickrClient.photos_getinfo(photo_id='photoid')" and I want to write the response attributes in a file where I'm able to use the data.

Comment: sorry, [this](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getInfo.html) actually gives XML as a response. Can you post your code? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451600/python-newbie-parse-xml-from-api-call) is a similar question. tree.write('output.xml') writes the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
import flickrapi
import os
from xml.etree import ElementTree

api_key = '6613deslkjfsldfsödflsdjfsjdla7e'
api_secret = '35lksdjöfadfs975'
user_id = '34543535@XXX'


flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, api_secret)

(token, frob) = flickr.get_token_part_one(perms='write')
if not token: raw_input("Press ENTER after you authorized this program")
flickr.get_token_part_two((token, frob))

sets = flickr.photosets_getList(user_id)

for set in sets.getchildren()[0]:
    title = set.getchildren()[0].text

    filename = "%s.txt" % (title)
    f = open(filename,'w')
    print ("Getting Photos from set: %s") % (title)
    for photo in flickr.walk_set(set.get('id')):
                f.write("%s" % (photo.get('title')))
    f.close()
```

to find out your Flickr-ID
[idGettr](http://idgettr.com/)

Comment: I stored Flickr response as xml file but what exactly I want to save is the attributes in txt file like: image id=1234 userId=... tilte=... and so on. I used .getroot() where I can store the attributes of first element but I could not get the rest. I'll illustrate my code below.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import os
import urllib
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import tostring
import flickrapi

 api_key = '             '
 api_password = '     '
 photo_id='2124494179'
 flickr= flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, api_password)
#photos= flickr.photos_getinfo(photo_id='15295705890')
#tree=ElementTree(flickr.photos_getinfo(photo_id))
#image_id=open('photoIds.txt','r')
#Image_data=open('imageinformation','w')
#e=image_id.readlines(10)
#f= [s.replace('\r\n', '') for s in e]
#num_of_lines=len(f)
#image_id.close()
#i=0
#while i<269846:
# term=f[i]
#try:
photoinfo=flickr.photos_getinfo(photo_id=photo_id)
photo_tree=ElementTree(photoinfo)
#photo_tree.write('photo_tree')
#i+=1
#photo=photo_tree.getroot()
#photodata=photo.getiterator()
#for elem in owner.getiterator():
#for elem in photo.getiterator():
for elem in photo_tree.getroot():
  farm=elem.attrib['farm']
  id=elem.attrib['id']
  server=elem.attrib['server']
  #title=photo_tree.find('title').txt
   #for child in elem.findall():
     # username=child.attrib['username']
     # location=child.attrib['location']
     #  user=elem.attrib['username']
print (farm)
print(id)
print(server)
strong text#owner=photo_tree.findall('owner')
# print(username)
#filename="%s.txt"%(farm)
#f=open(filename,'w')
#f.write("%s"%farm)
#for elem in photo_tree.getiterator():
 #for child in photo_tree.getiterator():
 #print (child.attrib)
 #owner=child.attrib['username']
```

I need to store the attributes in a txt file since I have to read a huge amount of image Ids from a file in order to obtain their info. where I can use it to as input to the algorithm that need these data to operate.