# How to interact with an XML API if i am using ODOO?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I am new to Odoo and i need to build up an e-commerce system, and i need to send and receive data from an API that was built by a small company in my country ...

i have looked up Odoo API, but that seems a little bit of the point that i am looking for, as Odoo API seems to talk about interacting with Odoo it self... while i am looking on how to interact from Odoo to another API.

I found some resources on how to parse XML with python in this [StackOverFlow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451600/python-newbie-parse-xml-from-api-call).

and i know what python code to execute after the response from the other company's API (thanks to Odoo [API Integration Docs](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/api_integration.html)), which is basically something like this:

```
//imporint the library xml-RPC
    import xmlrpclib
//connecting to the server
    info = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('https://demo.odoo.com').start()
//providing login parameters
    url, db, username, password = \
    info['host'], info['database'], info['user'], info['password']
    uid = common.authenticate(db, username, password, {})
//connecting to a model and calling a function
    models = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url))
    models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
    'res.partner', 'check_access_rights',
    ['read'], {'raise_exception': False})
//etc
```

All of this is understandable, the main question is where does this code need to go for it to be called every time the user needs to interact with the API? do i include the code in a button so that when the users clicks "interact " the API would be called? and it's response would be parsed with the above code?

Kindest regards,

Comment: You can start at https://doc.odoo.com/6.0/developer/6_22_XML-RPC_web_services/

Comment: @WalR thanks for the help, it seems that this is the same documentation like [the one i found](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/api_integration.html) but in an older version.

Answer (score 0):

yes, create a global function and call it on button.